# How to use hover to display the block from sibling parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Using ScSS, I want to display the block with class parent2, On hovering child 1 of block with class name as parent 1.

```
    <div classname="main">
      <div className="parent1">
    
        <span>    Child 1    </span>
        <span>    Child 2    </span>
        <span>    Child 3    </span>
      </div> 
      <div className="parent2">
    
        <span>        Child 1    </span>
        <span>        Child 2    </span>
        <span>        Child 3    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to move the parent 2 inside the child1 so you can trigger it with a hover like this:

```
.parent2{
  display: none;
}
.child1:hover .parent2 {
  display: block;
}

<div class="main">
      <div class="parent1">
    
 <div class="child1"> Child 1 
        <div class="parent2">
        <span>        Child 1    </span>
        <span>        Child 2    </span>
        <span>        Child 3    </span>
    </div>
</div>
      </div> 
      </div>
        <span>    Child 2    </span>
        <span>    Child 3    </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I dont want to move parent inside child.. Is there other way I can do it it without moving ?